# Regex command to match combinations but not only uppercase letters

Tags: regex, regex-group

Is there a regex command to match all combinations of uppercase letters, lowercase, underscore, brackets, numbers, but not only Uppercase letter words or only numbers?

I thought i had it with this one:

```
(/\b(?![A-Z]+\b)(?![0-9]+\b)[a-zA-Z0-9_{}]+\b/)
```

That was until i encountered: `ABC{hello}_HI_HelLo`

This is not a match, and i would like my regex to match this string.

There seem to be something with the negative lookahead since it reads "ABC" and assumes it is a Uppercase letter word only so it does not match the string, only the part after the "{" is matched.

When you add an underscore after "ABC" you get a matching string: ABC_{hello}_HI_HelLo

Comment: The is a wordboundary between `_{` You could use whitespace boundaries instead `(?<!\S)(?![A-Z]+(?!\S))(?![0-9]+(?!\S))[a-zA-Z0-9_{}]+` https://regex101.com/r/JzHVUZ/1

Comment: Did the answer work out?

Comment: Hi!
Yes it did indeed work out! 
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a word boundary between `_` and `{`

You can assert a whitespace boundary to the left `(?<!\S)` and the right `(?!\S)` instead.

The pattern matches:

- `(?<!\S)` Assert a whitespace boundary to the left
- `(?![A-Z]+(?!\S))` Assert not only uppercase chars followed by a whitespace boundary at the right
- `(?![0-9]+(?!\S))` Assert not only digits followed by a whitespace boundary at the right
- `[a-zA-Z0-9_{}]+` Match 1 or more occurrences of any of the listed

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JzHVUZ/1)